# Why $\tan x$ is not infinity at all the points > $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, periodic-functions, trigonometric-series

Looking at the series expansion of $\tan x$, it appears as the monotonically increasing function which we know isn't true. So, how can we describe it's periodicity from it's Maclaurin series?

Comment: The McLauin series of the tangent has a restricted interval of convergence. So it doesn't really make sense to talk about periodicity here...See this link:https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Taylor_Series_Expansion_for_Tangent_Function.

Comment: For a simpler example of the same phenomenon, take the Maclaurin series for $1/(1-x)$.  Looks monotonically increasing too, but for $x>1$ the function is negative.  It's not safe to draw conclusions about a function by looking at its Taylor series outside its interval of convergence.

Answer (score 3):

The Taylor series of a smooth function at a point need not converge everywhere; even if it does, [it may not equal the function everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function)! In this case, the Taylor series at $0$ converges and agrees with tangent on the connected component of the graph containing the origin; but this isn't the whole graph! So the rest of the tangent function is invisible to the Taylor series at zero.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Never knew there existed such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* that it's because the function is discontinuous (and undifferentiable) at $x= \pm \frac{ \pi}{2}$. Since Taylor series rely only on continuity and looks at the derivatives at a single point, in theory it *should* rapidly diverge to infinity after $x= \pm \frac{ \pi}{2}$ (not sure if it actually does).

Comment: MIght want to change to $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$